# How to append custom tableviewcells to tableview one by one

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have two tableview controllers lets say PopoverElementsListTable ,ElementsViewTable. one tableview will be in popover state when I click on one of the PopoverElementsListTable cell a custom cell has to added to the ElementsViewTable.I'm able to append only one cell when I try to add another cell to ElementsViewTable its getting replaced with previous cell.

```
#pragma mark - TableView delegate

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:
(NSInteger)section{
    if (tableView == PopoverElementsListTable) {
        return  [myArray count];
    }
    else if (tableView == ElementsViewTable) {
       return 1;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (tableView == PopoverElementsListTable) {
        static NSString *cellId = @"autoaddress";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
                                 cellId];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:
                    UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellId];
        }
        cell.textLabel.text = [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        return cell;
    }else {
        NSLog(@"_selectedIndex %lu",(unsigned long)_selectedIndex);
        if(_selectedIndex == 1){
            AutoFillAddressFormElementcell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"autoAddressCell"];
            if (!cell) {
                cell = [[AutoFillAddressFormElementcell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"autoAddressCell"];
            }
            return cell;
        }else if(_selectedIndex == 2){
            NSLog(@"Test @ 123");
            AddressSetterFormElementCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"setAddressCell"];
            if (!cell) {
                cell = [[AddressSetterFormElementCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"setAddressCell"];
            }
            return cell;
        }else{
                static NSString *cellId = @"autoaddress";
                UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];
                if (cell == nil) {
                    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:
                            UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellId];
                }
                cell.textLabel.text = @"List";
                return cell;
            }
        }
   }


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if(tableView == PopoverElementsListTable){
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSLog(@"Section:%ld Row:%ld selected and its data is %@",
              (long)indexPath.section,(long)indexPath.row,cell.textLabel.text);
        [_transarentView setHidden:true];
        _selectedIndex = indexPath.row + 1;
        NSLog(@"number %lu",(unsigned long)_selectedIndex);
       [_displayFromElementTableView reloadData];
    }
    if(tableView == ElementsViewTable){

    }
}
```

I know I'm able to append only one item because of return 1 in numberOfRowsInSection delegate. I tried replacing with another number but what I achieved is all the cells are identical.How can I get the dynamic count here? How to append customcells one by one which are unidentical.

Answer (score -1):

- You need to do it by identifying indexpath .

  ```
  if (indexPath.row == 0) {
      Customcell1 *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
  }else if (indexPath.row == 1){
      Customcell2 *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
  }
  return cell;
  ```

  and so on....
  You can check the table view too if you want.